# form_radio in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

**normally in ratio button only 1 Option can select at a time**. but in CodeIgniter I can select both at a time. May I know how can I fix this Problem?

echo form_open ('main/signup_validation');

```
        echo "<p> Gender : ";
echo form_radio('male','male');
echo form_radio('female','female');     
echo "</p>"; 

        echo form_close();
```

Are we doing this in Validation Part or Can I do in above Code? thanks in advance.

**Signature : http://www.WorldQuotes.in**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Name should be same for both radio buttons

```
  echo form_radio('gender','male');
  echo form_radio('gender','female');
```

Comment: Ya sure Pramod. I tried to do it but stackoverflow pop shows a time limit before tick on answer. now its less than 1 min. :-)

Comment: Pramod May I know how to display the text before radio button. in above code its not coming 

is below code right?

<?php echo form_radio('gender','male','Male'); ?>

Comment: <?php echo form_label('Male', 'gender');?>?php echo form_radio('gender','male','Male'); ?>

Comment: : I did below way and its displaying properly. no mistakes right?

  `<td>Male :
  <?php echo form_radio('gender','male'); ?>
  </td>`

Comment: Yeah. there is no problem in this